# How can I shorten a hexadecimal string further?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, encoding

I am using MongoDB's build in id fields to label products and for ease of usage/typability, I would like to compress the _id field down from a hexadecimal string that looks like `5b69c35ac2cc78c8979a8a9b` to something shorter and involving all letters of the alphabet (both uppercase and lowercase) and numbers.  preferably it would involve no more than 10 or 12 characters.  Are there any common methods of accomplishing this in Node.JS/MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert them to base64, that would make them 16 characters long.

Example:

```
Buffer.from('5b69c35ac2cc78c8979a8a9b', 'hex').toString('base64') // W2nDWsLMeMiXmoqb
```

It's better if you can directly access the `Buffer` - converting many ObjectIds from string could be costly.

Comment: would it be possible to shorten it just a tad bit more?

Comment: What range of characters are you allowed to use?

Comment: anything that works in a URL although I would prefer to leave out '-' and '_' for readability

Comment: so as far as I know that would be a-z A-Z 0-9

Comment: The ObjectId is 12 bytes and if you want to use it in url - I am afraid - 16 chars is as low as you can go. Also check https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-url. Standard base64 includes `+` and `/`.

Answer (score 1):

The code `5b69c35ac2cc78c8979a8a9b` is 24 bytes long (in hex), which means the absolute minimum number of bytes needed to represent this value without losing information is 12, ranging from 0-255 which is not what we want.

If we take a look at the [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) we could (maybe) eliminate some bytes:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Removing `machine identifier` and `process id` (if all id's are generated by the same process) would leave us with 7 bytes (0-255), which is still not ideal to encode in base64 or even base32.

So it would probably be better to just use a 32 bit unsigned integer for the product codes and display it as hex using 8 bytes (the leading zeros could be removed).

Encoding those 4 bytes in base64 wouldn't help much (every 3 bytes become 4 bytes), and personally I would prefer case insensitive id's for use in url's which would leave us only with [base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32).

For better ease of usage/typability than hexadecimal, those 4 bytes could be encoded in [z-base-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#z-base-32) and would fit in 7 bytes without padding (7 * 5 bits = 35 bits).